# with shell script ,how to find number line in text

Tags: shell

I`m trying to find lines which match the pattern x.y or x.y.z, where x,y and z are numbers.

For example, given the lines:

```
1.0/
2.2.5rc1/
2.3.0/
2.3.1/
abc-1.0.0/
```

the result should be:

```
1.0  
2.3.0  
2.3.1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: your example doesn't quite make sense. I can see `2.3.0` and `2.3.1` matching `x.y` and `x.y.z`, but given `x=2;y=3`, how can `1.0` match for `x.y`? Please elaborate or clarify ;-) Good luck.

Comment: ＠shellter，you suggestion is right. I just do not know how to describe it .However, what the result which i want is:
1.0  
2.3.0  
2.3.1

Comment: Add the output of `grep --version` to you question above. Good luck.

Comment: david@workstation:~$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 2.16
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
david@workstation:~$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to know:

1. Call `grep` in extended mode using `-E`.
2. start the pattern with a `^` to signify you want the search to start at the first character.
3. To search for a digit, use `\d`
4. To search for a dot, use `\.`
5. To search for thing1 OR thing1, use `thing1|thing2`.

Note: As Jonathan Leffler pointed out below, `\d` is a notation that might not work across all version of grep. Try `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` to be compliant in POSIX-standard implementations of grep.

Knowing that, we put it together like so:

`grep -E "^(\d.\d.|\d.\d.\d)/" yourfile`

Comment: @ z5h your solution seems good one .i tried you suggestion,but it output nothing..    thanks!

Comment: @planetradio: `\d` is a Perl-ish notation which might be available in GNU `grep` (especially if you use `-P` instead of `-E`); it may or may not be available in your version of `grep`.  Try replacing each `\d` with `[0-9]` (or, if you don't mind being ultra-verbose, `[[:digit:]]`).  That will work in POSIX-standard versions of `grep`.

Comment: grep -P  "^(\d.\d|\d.\d.\d)/" yourfile  is OK.
In The Other Hand,
grep -P  "^([[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+|[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+)/" yourfile
is OK too.

now,it works!
thanks to all!
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
grep -C 2 yourSearch yourFile
```

To send it in a file, do

```
grep -C 2 yourSearch yourFile > result.txt
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Assuming `grep -C 2` is supposed to give two lines of context before and after a match (that's what it means in Mac OS X or BSD `grep`, anyway), it doesn't seem to be providing an answer to the question.  It would help if you explained what it was supposed to do.